# How to create a Wordpress Mega Menu Walker?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am new to the Wordpress Walker class and i am trying to find out how to create a walker for a Mega Menu that will output this:

```html
<nav id="mega-menu" class="mega-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container"> <!-- 100% width -->
                <div class="sub-menu-inner"> <!-- Columns container -->
                    <div> <!-- first column -->
                        <h4>This is first column</h4> <!-- Column title -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                            <!-- ... -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div> <!-- second column -->
                        <h4>This is the second column</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /sub-menu-inner -->
            </div><!-- /sub-menu-container -->
        </li>
        <li><!-- ... --></li>
        <li><!-- ... --></li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Would really like to know how a walker would be in this case :) 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you see this question and answer? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/150010/mega-menu-walker

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Bootstrap, here’s a menu walker that’s an amazing starting point:

https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

https://gist.github.com/nekojira/5864215

This can help you.

Answer (score 0):

For building wordpress megamenu you need the array of your menu with a certain location.I have worked out for rendering the array of menu with it submenus and you can loop through it according to your requirement if you have simple PHP knowledge.[Here](http://subodhdhukuchhu.com.np/get-wordpress-menu-items-in-multidimensional-array/) is the function to render the array,